# good jquery content separators

Tags: javascript, jquery

just wondering if anyone knows of any pre built content switchers powered by jquery like the one depicted below (only have a screenshot, otherwise I wouldn't be asking :P):

[image]

Comment: U mean tabs ? on the left? how lazy are you ? its a css thing not a jquery, (well you could have it in jQuery) but would be silly to have a plugin that most ppl aint going to use it

Comment: What do you mean, the tab on the left?

Comment: +1 for how lazy are you!

Comment: Lazy yes. No it's not really a CSS thing, I need jQuery because all the content is on one page, not multiple pages. It's fine I'll just build it myself. jeez relax thanks anyways lol

Comment: Not sure why everyone is calling you lazy, it's clearly a tab functionality which, as pointed out, exists in the jQueryUI library, and the question is totally valid and legitimate. Widgets in the library are made for people to use, and you needn't reinvent the wheel yourself. There's no downvote for comments, but in spirit, -1 for the lazy comment, no need to namecall here. Not to mention that code reuse is one of the most time and money saving strategies of both the IT industry and by way of extension all of the exact sciences.

Comment: Furthermore, making a fully functioning, customizable, accessible tabs widget is not trivial.

Comment: thanks, I am going to use the UI widget

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be pretty easy to just use the [jQuery Tabs UI Widget](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/) and just re-style the tabs/tab container to float to the left of the content. The "Theming" tab on that page shows you the structure it uses.

The CSS would be something similar to this (based on the example markup of the Theming tab):

```
#tabs > ul {
    width: 20%;
    float: left;
}
#tabs > ul > li {
    display: block;
}
#tabs > div {
    width: 80%;
    float: right;
}
```